# How to get data from sql server table. If values contains some special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have inserted data in to table name is Testing with special characters. Insertion was successful but while fetching same record with where condition then its not showing any record.

Testing table data looks like

| group_id | directory_id | group_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | BDC2_Igénykezelők |

```
select *from Testing where group_name ='BDC2_Igénykezelők';
```

result showing zero records above query. I am not able identify why its not fetching that record.

Comment: what is the datatype of that column, varchar or nvarchar ?

Comment: Try what happens when you run `SELECT 'BDC2_Igénykezelők', N'BDC2_Igénykezelők'`

Comment: `'BDC2_Igénykezelők'` should be `N'BDC2_Igénykezelők'`.